# No function matches the given name and argument types (PostgreSQL 10.3 -CentOs 7.4)

Tags: postgresql, centos, putty

My function when excecuted in SQL Manager works wittout error.
But when I use Putty and the command line, I can connect to my database, but when I try to run this function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION s_sco."Group" (
)
RETURNS void AS
$body$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO tab1 ("group", "Name", "creator", "dat", "mod", "datm")
select distinct tab2.SSI,tab2.LIB , '123456', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '', to_timestamp('01/01/1900','DD/MM/YYYY') from tab2 WHERE 
         NOT EXISTS (select group from tab1 where group IN 
         (select SSI from tab2));

END;

$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

I keep getting this error :

```
Function () does not exist.
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: Might be because `group` is a reserved word? Perhaps try to rename the function and re-run the test...

Comment: Nah. Please show the statement that produces the error.

Comment: I renamed the function "GroupS", still the same problem. The statement is "select GroupS();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that all the functions with names that had upper case characters caused this error,so I renamed them all with lower case and I don't have the error anymore.